# Strange behaviour when adding directive dynamically in ngrepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

I am trying to add a directive dynamically inside ngrepeat.  Please refer to the following fiddle link:  [Fiddle Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/2i6Fc44E6XROMCqkSlBP?p=info)

**Code:**

```
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

// myDir Directive
app.directive('myDir', function() {
    var controller = ['$scope','$compile', function ($scope,$compile) {

    $scope.names=[{id:'1',directive:'subDir1'},{id:'2',directive:'subDir2'}];

    $scope.loadDynamicDir = function(id, directive) {
      var newScope = $scope.$new(true);
      var html = $compile('<div class="' + directive + '"></div>')(newScope);
      angular.element(document.getElementById('div' + id)).append(html);
    }
  }]

  return {
    controller:controller,
    templateUrl:'myDirTemplate.html'
  }

})

// subDir1 Directive
app.directive('subDir1', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'C',
    template: 'subDir1'
  }
});

// subDir2 Directive
app.directive('subDir2', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'C',
    template: 'subDir2'
  }
});
```

Unfortunatley, each directive is added 3 times. Can anyone explain the exact behaviour?

Comment: Adding More, when I use templateUrl in the sub directives, it is throwing error. Fiddle link for the same is  [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/bu6GfqKVafLcxPc7UFO7?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple. EVERY function added to template will run at least twice as `$digest` cycle runs twice - first after model change, and second to check if first cycle changed any model

so your function `loadDynamicDir` will run everytime there is `$digest` and since you APPEND the html everytime it creates more nodes

I've added button to your plunker showing the behaviour

https://plnkr.co/edit/4hpVDOPJm2BMzSwRcm5N?p=preview

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <my-dir></my-dir>
  <button ng-click="$digest()">do digest</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain this behaviour also - when I use templateUrl in the sub directives, it is throwing error. [Fiddle Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/bu6GfqKVafLcxPc7UFO7?p=preview)

Comment: It's the same, infinite digest. Every time you compile directive you trigger $digest, and every time $digest runs it triggers the function from template and do another compile, and so on forever (if there was no limit in digests)